# How can I skip the first cell in a NSCollectionView?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

How can NSCollectionView items begin at the second cell and leave the first cell empty? [(View Example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlRhw.png)

Comment: Just add dummy transparent cell

Answer (score 0):

**Ugly easy way:**

Just disable user interaction in the first cell and hide it.

```
view.isHidden = true
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

**Correct way:**

Register a new invisible cell class with the NSCollectionView and return in just on the first row.